# Trigonometric functions properties

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

So I have a test next week and I have this question which I do know how to solve and I have no direction how to prove that.

Any help would be appreciated.

> $$ \forall (x_{1}\land x_{2}) \in \left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right),\ x_{1} < x_{2} \Longrightarrow \ \dfrac{x_{1}}{x_{2}} < \dfrac{\sin(x_{1})}{\sin(x_{2})}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: The inequality you want to show is equivalent to

$$\frac{\sin x_2}{x_2} < \frac{\sin x_1}{x_1}$$

for $0 < x_1 < x_2 < \pi/2$, since $\sin x > 0$ for $0 < x < \pi/2$.

So show that $$\frac{\sin x}{x}$$ is a decreasing function on $(0,\pi/2)$, for example by differentiating.

Comment: First of all thank u !! so I followed your direction and I derivative the function and I reached this : $\frac{xcos(x)-sin(x)}{x^{2}}$ . If I show that the derivtive is always $ < 0 $ I will finish proof is exactly like showing that $x < tan(x)$ for all $x$ in range. So how do I continue from here ? I guess I just need someone to guide if I have no solution in front of me. Thanks again !!

Comment: Okay, now you want to show that $f(x) = \sin x - x\cos x$ is positive on $(0,\,\pi/2)$. Clearly, $f(0) = 0$. What can you say about the derivative $f'(x)$?

Comment: I got it !!! Thanks !!! Thank u very much !!